# Is there a good way to find out if a Grandmaster exists for a skill?

Tags: 7th-sea

*Knights of the Rose and Cross* introduced the concept of Grandmasters -- NPCs who could be convinced to train a character up to a sixth dot in a skill.

That book included the following NPCs:

- Sprague (Attack (Fencing))
- Rachel Milligan (Leaping)
- Marcos San Felipe (Surgery)

Each book since *Knights of the Rose and Cross* has introduced a few new Grandmasters.

My players are starting to reach the ends of advancement, and are looking for ways to quest for final improvements. Some of the players have asked about Grandmasters, specifically in Attack (Heavy Weapon).

I realize that I could just make an NPC up, but if a canon Grandmaster exists I'd like to use him to help tie my campaign into the overarching meta plot. Is there any way to look up the Grandmaster for a skill, short of flipping through each individual book?

Comment: Irrespective of what you find, a good quest would be for the characters to go about discovering, getting to, and convincing said grandmaster to teach them.

Comment: @Okeefe Yep, that's the plan. And knowing the "real" NPC would give me a lot of fodder for designing the quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list from the **7th Sea Character Handbook (01-2004)**.

---

Die Kreuzritter p. 69:

- Ambush = Kazi, at Altamira
- Stealth = Kazi, at Altamira
- Tracking = Kazi, at Altamira

The Invisible College pp. 78-79:

- Mathematics = Reimar Derviny, Vestenmannavnjar
- Research = Ravenild Hibbot, Avalon
- Natural Philosophy = Alvara Arciniega, Castille

Los Vagos p. 77:

- Disguise = Don Hector Ontiveros
- Footwork = Don Cristian Acedo de Lopez del Torres
- Ride = Dona Ximena de Gallegos

Rilasciare pp. 77-78:

- Lockpicking = Gabriel Menendez de Altamira, Altamira
- Logistics = Nolan Chaucer, at Kirk
- Oratory = Boris Nicholeivich Sokolov, at Pavtlow

The Rose and Cross p. 66:

- Attack (Fencing) = Sprague, at The Dungeon
- Leaping = Rachel Mulligan, at Carleon House
- Surgery = Marcos San Filipe, at San Cristobal Library

Sophia's Daughters p. 82:

- History = Fidencia Suarez, Rancho Aldana
- Natural Philosophy = Reune Vengasdotter, whereabouts unknown
- Seduction = Madame Lorraine Weller, Kirk

The Swordsman’s Guild p. 82:

- Attack (Heavy Weapon) = Hrodgeir, Viddenheim
- Footwork = Linnae Knute, Kirk
- Parry (Knife) = Sebastien Valroux de Martise, Echine

Also, several combat schools allow members to increase given knacks to rank 6 at certain levels of mastery.

---

I strongly suggest you to download and use the following fan-made compendiums for 7th Sea: [**7th Sea Player's Compendium**](http://www.oocities.org/timessquare/tower/4105/7thSeaIntro.pdf) and the handbooks and other good stuff from [**Crystal Keep**](http://www.crystalkeep.com/7thsea/). They are so much help in the game.

Comment: Thank you for the list and the links. It figures that the one I'm after is in the super rare and expensive book :-P

Comment: Yeah, it is a must if you have combat oriented characters in the party, which I'm sure you do with the rank 6 request. Soon, they'll want to found their own school. :)